# Is one allowed to go to a standup comedy show during the 3 weeks?

Tags: halacha, nine-days, three-weeks, humor, performance-entertainment

I know that one is not allowed to listen to ***live* music** during the 3 weeks.

My question is if Standup comedy is not allowed as well?

Comment: The music restriction for _Ashk'nazim_ (whatever it is) is on the three weeks, AFAIK, not only the nine days. But CYLOR of course for a ruling.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @msh210, true, but the question can still apply to schachna's case.  Perhaps the 3 weeks are limited to specific restrictions based on custom.  Whereas during the 9 days there is a general idea of mema'atin b'simcha.

Comment: @HachamGabriel, just a guess, but perhaps someone did not like the emphasis on the word "live" since that point is debated.

Comment: +1. I suspect that the OP only emphasized the _live_ part, since that's the less controversial point. Ironic, that.

Comment: Is there some reason משנכנס אב ממעטין בשמחה is not the correct answer to this question?

Comment: @DoubleAA Because the first two weeks of Bein HaMetzarim are Tamuz.

Comment: I doubt you'd find anyone saying this is explicitly forbidden according to the letter of the law (at least, with regards to the laws of the 3 weeks). Probably goes against the spirit of the law, but that's a different discussion altogether.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### 1) No

**[R' Shlomo Aviner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Aviner)** takes a strict approach and [writes](http://www.havabooks.co.il/sms.asp?cat=58) unequivocally  that the answer is no (#17 from the top).

> **סטנדאפ בבין המצרים**
>   ש: מותר ללכת למופע סטנדאפ?
>
> **Standup during the 3 weeks**: Q: Is one allowed to go to a standup show?
>
> ת: **ודאי אסור**. אסור כל השנה בגלל מושב ליצים. ע"ז יח ב. קל וחומר בין המצרים
>
> A: **Definitely forbidden**. [Going to a standup show is] forbidden year round because it falls under the category of "sitting with the scornful" ([Avodah Zarah 18b](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.18b.11-16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi)). All the more so during the 3 weeks.

### 2) No... but maybe there are a couple of exceptions

In a (Hebrew) **kipa.co.il** article titled "[סטנדאפ בבין המצרים](https://www.kipa.co.il/%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%9C-%D7%90%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91/%D7%A1%D7%98%D7%A0%D7%93%D7%90%D7%A4-%D7%91%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D1/)" - "Standup During the 3 Weeks,
  R' Uziel Eliyahu writes: (translation mine)

> "When Av arrives we lessen our happiness" therefore one would not be allowed to go to a standup show during the 9 days.

R' Eliyahu also notes at the end:

> **It's obviously preferable to postpone this until after the 3 weeks.**

However in the middle part of his answer, R' Eliyahu writes:

> During the 3 weeks (before Rosh Chodesh Av) one should also avoid going to a show like this. However, if **a summer camp for children** or **a pre-arranged program** **or there is a special reason**-- **like a person who's in a state of depression or loneliness**-- [said person] **is certainly allowed to go to the show and this could even be a big *mitzvah***!!! Furthermore, if the choice is between going to this show or getting bored and the boredom leading to sinning in other ways it's certainly preferable for such a person to go to this show.
>
> Sometimes from going to a show like this a person leaves it with *chizuk* since the laughter removes a person from his condition and can greatly elevates his *Avodas Hashem*.

---

### So to sum up:

R' Aviner is a hard no, and even according to R' Eliyahu of **kipa.co.il** in order for an allowance to be made it would really have to be an extenuating circumstance.

I think it's also safe to say that this question was asked re: Kosher standup, as non-Kosher standup is prohibited year round.

To be safe, should **[CYLOR](https://www.yourdictionary.com/cylor)**.

Comment: Wouldn't Rav Aviner agree on a case of a depressed person?

Comment: @sam possibly (or even likely)- but one can't say for sure since it isn't addressed in the answer cited